# How to apply conditional formatting for multiple cells depending on multiple cell values without AND or OR

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

This is my excel sheet

```
Row         B
------------------------
1          Task - Color should be green because B700="Completed"
------------------------
2          Done
3          Not done
4          Done
5          Done
.
.
700        Completed
.
.
1000
------------------------
```

**Here formatting I need:**

*If any cell value of the second column = "Completed" background color = "green"*

**Formula could be of this sort cant use AND or OR because on too many cells:**

*=Any one or more cell from($B2:$B1000) = Completed*

Comment: Not sure i fully understand, so your only condition is if cells in `B` say completed? Use `=$B2="Completed"` with the range set as `$B$2:$B$1000`.

Comment: @TimWilkinson I clearly wrote Any one or more cell from($B2:$B1000) = Completed. Which means at-least one cell of column B should have value as completed. If it is true the heading cell color will be green or any color you like.

Comment: If it was clear I wouldn't have asked the question. My suggestion satisfies `If any cell value of the second column = "Completed" background color = "green"`, but now I see you just wanted the heading changing green, as per Mark's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With B1 selected, in the Conditional Formatting dialogue click "Use a formula to determine which cells to format. In the formula box enter `=COUNTIF(B:B,"Completed")` and then select your green fill in the format dialogue.

The test formula doesn't need to test if the function evaluation is TRUE using an IF function (i.e. `=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,"Completed")>0,TRUE,FALSE)  )` because in this context Excel evaluates 0 = FALSE and any other number as TRUE.

You could substitute `B:B` with your actual used range but the performance gain is likely to be imperceptible.